# php : use str_replace( ); on some condition?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

my text:

> bob have message123 and alice has message

i want:

> bob have newmessage and alice has newmessage

My current code is:

```
$fullText= str_replace("message123", "newmessage", $fulltext);
$fullText= str_replace("message", "newmessage", $fulltext);
```

but it becomes:

> bob have newnewmessage and alice has newmessage

- 'new' is repeated because str_replace(); search whole text and find replace again.
- is it possible not to replace the text which is already replaced.

Comment: You can also pass array of strings as parameters in `str_replace` ex: `str_replace( array( "message", "newmessage1" ), "newmessage", $fullText );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest solution, you could just add spaces:

```
$fullText= str_replace(" message1 ", " newmessage ", $fulltext);
$fullText= str_replace(" message ", " newmessage ", $fulltext);
```

Or using multiple needles:

```
$fullText = str_replace(array(' message1 ', ' message '), array(' newmessage ', ' newmessage '), $fullText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use preg_replace.

In this case:

```
$fullText=preg_replace("/\bmessage[0-9]*/", "newmessage", $fullText);
```

which will replace message, message1, message2 etc.

Comment: If you're not familiar with regex:

/ marks the beginning and end of the search string,
\b looks for the beginning of a new word boundary
[0-9]* looks for zero or more numbers at the end of the string "message"

Answer (score 0):

Use the strtr() function -- it will not pass again over stuff that it already replaced:

```
$fullText = 'bob have message1 and alice has message without 1.';
$fullText = strtr( $fullText, array(
    "message1" => "newmessage",
    "message" => "newmessage" ) );
```